# What is ReactComponent and where does it come from when importing an svg in React?

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm following a tutorial and in it a .svg file is being imported as a component. The line of code is:

`import {ReactComponent as OfferIcon} from '../assets/svg/localOfferIcon.svg';`.

I understand that the .svg file is being imported as a component, however, I dont understand where ReactComponent comes from? I've checked the .svg file and it isn't mentioned in it. Is this a special keyword when importing an .svg file? If someone can point me to the documentation then that would also be nice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you are using Create React App. Create React App uses [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) to transform `.svg` files so you can just import them in your React app. The svg file is transformed in a way that it exports a React component called "ReactComponent". That's why you have to import "ReactComponent" from the file and then rename it to whatever you would like!

Find more information in this [really nice blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-svgs-in-react/). Basically, you can just use `<svg>` tags in your JSX. However, if you want to import `.svg` files, you will need a transformer that transforms the content of the file into a React component, which just returns the `<svg>` content in JSX.